# @types/youtube + create-react-app + TypeScript = Cannot access ambient const enums when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided

Tags: typescript

I'm using create-react-app and typescript and @types/youtube for development.

When I type this line at code `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING`.

I get TypeScript error `Cannot access ambient const enums when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.`

And I look at the typing:

```
declare namespace YT
{
    /**
     * State of a video player.
     */
    export const enum PlayerState
    {
        UNSTARTED = -1,
        ENDED = 0,
        PLAYING = 1,
        PAUSED = 2,
        BUFFERING = 3,
        CUED = 5
    }
...
```

How can I solve this problem without turning the flag `isolatedModules` to false?